# Setting up OpenGL 3.3 in SDL 1.2

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, mingw, eclipse

I've been using SDL 1.2.14 for awhile without using many of the features from newer OpenGL versions. I'm now interested working only with the 3.3 API (not using the deprecated functions, etc... that's the latest my graphics card supports), but I'm having trouble getting set up.

Here's some information about my development environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Eclipse Helios CDT
- Mingw Toolchain
- C++

I've tried building SDL 1.3 and following [this tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1%3a_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_%28C_/_SDL%29). This ended up being a pretty big pain and I gave up amid a stream of compile errors - I'd prefer to not go this route if possible. I know also that GLEW/GLEE or some do-it-yourself extension function pointers will be required.

So basically: is it possible? If so, what is the best/easiest way to make it happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only SDL version 1.3 provides support for creating an OpenGL 3.3 **core** context. So you should upgrade. And if you're having a problem upgrading, that's something you need to get worked out.

However, if you want to use a 3.3 **[compatibility](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts)** context, all you need is recent drivers. Well, that and 3.3-capable hardware (anything advertised as DX10. Except from Intel).